# Using sort order to adapt a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Wonder if anyone can help - I'm using a plugin called sz subpage list, which is great, But I need to use the "order" which you can specify in the wp-admin, and the plugin doesnt appear to support this.

I'm trying the following, but it doesnt seem to work - any ideas ?

Basically I replaced the

```
$pages = get_pages();
```

for

```
$pages = get_pages('sort_order=menu_order&sort_order=asc');
```

here's the original, any ideas ?

Thanks for looking

```
function getPagesOptionList($selected) {
    $list = '';
    $pages = get_pages();
    foreach($pages as $page) {
        if ($selected == $page->ID) {
            $list .= '<option selected="selected" value="'.$page->ID.'">'.$page->post_title.' - (id: '.$page->ID.')</option>';
        } else {
            $list .= '<option value="'.$page->ID.'"">'.$page->post_title.' - (id: '.$page->ID.')</option>';
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just change the code if that works for you? It's a single line.

Comment: the code I have mentioned I tried, and it's not working when I drop it in, I was wondering if anyone knew why - as it seems it should do.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong line DOH!, further up I found this;

    $pages = get_pages('exclude='.$exclude.'&child_of='.$parent);

So I added this in

    $pages = get_pages('exclude='.$exclude.'&child_of='.$parent.'&sort_column=menu_order');

All working as should now :)

Comment: Add this as an answer to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the wrong line DOH!, further up I found this;

```
$pages = get_pages('exclude='.$exclude.'&child_of='.$parent);
```

So I added this in

```
$pages = get_pages('exclude='.$exclude.'&child_of='.$parent.'&sort_column=menu_order');
```

All working as should now :)